BitBucket - get number of comments and time in review for a list of PRs
I'm an engineering manager with the following thesis about pull requests in my team:
1. Long PRs take longer to review (disproportionate to their length in lines of code)
2. Long PRs receive less comments per line of code than shorter PRs
We're working with BitBucket. Is there a way to validate my thesis with actual statistics from BB? More specifically - for a list of given PRs can I get their length in number of code, the number of comments and the time it took from push to merge?
(I've looked at several git tools and similar questions, but nothing on BB PRs)

I don't think you will be able to get anything from git itself.

are you using Server or Cloud?

@jeremyFiel cloud

There is an app called jellyfish which I think gives some info about the PRs.
another way is to use the API for bitbucket cloud and create a script/program to retrieve the information:
https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v805/api-group-pull-requests/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-pull-requests-pullrequestid-blocker-comments-get
